# OpenCV bounding box and scale

Tags: c++, opencv, scaling, bounding-box

I must to put a bounding box on an object in a jpg file and scale it to a given width and length.
Is this possible? 
How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669611/bounding-box-using-opencv

Comment: http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

Comment: http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/

Comment: http://linuxconfig.org/resize-an-image-with-opencv-cvresize-function